# Zend Framework 2 get route by controller and action

Tags: php, zend-framework2

Could not find an answere here in so. Hope I didn't missed it.

I tried, but couldn't find a way to get the route by a given controller and action inf ZF2. I want to build an admin page for acls and I want to display the route for the resource. I build the resource dynamically from `Module/Controller/Action names`.

Lets say I have a Controller named `Application` and an action named `testAction`. In my module.config.php is the route `/application[:/action]` defined. Now I want to ask ZF2, which route has the controller "Application" with the method `testAction` and the result should be `application/test`.

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.module-manager.module-manager.html The module manager prob has a few listeners you could use for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible from any practical standpoint.

It is side effect of flexibility of routing in zf2. You can try to apply heavily limiting conventions for your routes, but that would be neither reliable or good decision.

Comment: Thank you. Thought something like that after searching and not found anything. I make this post as the correct answer, because I aksed of an internal Zend way. Nonetheless I will try to build a method that try to build the route by the config, as I commented @user1248927. Thanks.

Comment: You can try to design system in such way so your resource will have canonical routename and parameters required for assembling or may be canonical url stored. But that is very context specific and you are definitely not getting route by controller and action.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand correctly what you are trying to do.

while in controller application you can get current controller and action,

```
$controller = $this->params('controller');
$action = $this->params('action');
```

If this is not what you want please give more information.

Then would this help you?

```
$config = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Config');
print_r($config['router']);die;
```

Comment: No, I want to display one page with a list of all `Controllers` and their `Actions`. Now it would be nice, if I could get the route to every `Action`, so I can generate a link to that page. Its a nice to have, but I want it. I know I could parse the config array by myself and could find it, make some replaces and so on, but I think there is a Zend way to do it and i didn't find it yet.

Comment: i edited the answer with another block of code that might help you

Comment: Yeah, it's the manual thing I thought I don't have to do. Thought of something like `getRouteByControllerAndAction('Application', 'test')`., but as @Xerkus said, it is not really possible. I think I will try to build such a method, even if it would be ugly and not so good practise. As I said, its a nive to have and for an internal admin  page. Thanks.